# Autocomplete textview in fragments

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I want to create an autoCompleteTextView in a fragment but the Array adapter is bringing an error saying that 'none of the following function can be called with the arguments supplied'. So how should I use the array adapter in a fragment class?

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    val frequencyArray = ArrayList<String>()
    frequencyArray.add("Daily")
    frequencyArray.add("Weekly")
    frequencyArray.add("Monthly")

    val adapter = ArrayAdapter(
        this,
        com.google.android.material.R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
        frequencyArray
    )

    var autoComplete = view?.findViewById<AutoCompleteTextView>(R.id.notAuto)
    autoComplete?.setAdapter(adapter)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The constructor you're trying to use is [this one](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter#ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context,%20int,%20java.util.List%3CT%3E)):

```
public ArrayAdapter (Context context, 
                int resource, 
                List<T> objects)
```

The first parameter is a `Context` and you're passing `this`, i.e. the `Fragment`. But a Fragment *isn't* a `Context` (unlike an `Activity`) so you have to grab one. Just use `requireContext()` instead - you'll have one by the time `onViewCreated` is called ([you get it before `onCreate`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#onAttach(android.content.Context)))

```
    val adapter = ArrayAdapter(
        requireContext(),
        com.google.android.material.R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
        frequencyArray
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one?

```
class SecondFragment : Fragment() {

    lateinit var autoTextView : AutoCompleteTextView

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val inflate = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, false)

        autoTextView = inflate.findViewById(R.id.autoTextView)

        val languages
                = resources.getStringArray(R.array.Languages)

        // Create adapter and add in AutoCompleteTextView
        val adapter1
                = ArrayAdapter<String>(requireContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, languages)
        autoTextView.setAdapter(adapter1)

        return inflate
    }
}
```

and check https://prnt.sc/cQpmLyDO4WsV